# Getting data from Dynamics CRM 365 in json

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm-online

I need to get data from Dynamics CRM 365 Online. Anyone tried this before ?

I need to know what kind of information (clientid, clientsecret) I need, to connect through c sharp and save data (JSON) into a for example a flatfile.

edit:
use ADAL.Net v2 If you need to use the non async method. 
Remember to put the Token in the request header under "Authorization".

Comment: Use the `Microsoft.CrmSdk` packages. You will need your discovery address, unique organization name, username, password and domain. You can then serialise the `Entity` objects to JSON with the `Newtonsoft.Json` package

Comment: Do you have any example of code using that SDK?

Comment: Yes but it's an entire project in itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OAuth to authenticate to Dynamics 365 Online from your C# code.

```
// TODO Substitute your correct CRM root service address,   
string resource = "https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com";  

// TODO Substitute your app registration values that can be obtained after you  
// register the app in Active Directory on the Microsoft Azure portal.  
string clientId = "e5cf0024-a66a-4f16-85ce-99ba97a24bb2";  
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost/SdkSample";  

// Authenticate the registered application with Azure Active Directory.  
AuthenticationContext authContext =   
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);  
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));
```

You can then use the `AuthenticationResult` to make HTTP requests with `HttpClient`:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())  
{  
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  // 2 minutes  
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =   
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken); 
//TODO Implement your WebApi calls
}
```

These code samples and additional details, including how to register an application with Azure AD, are in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/connect-customer-engagement-web-services-using-oauth

Comment: Thank!. I do not have a redirectURl, I only have the resource. Is the redirecturl needed ?

Comment: See what they did with the same, just make one up - I usually use a domain I own with a non-existent page (just to avoid any problem.)

Comment: Have u used this before ? I keep getting an error that I cannot call authContext.AcquireToken without using the async. I have a very simple console application currently.

Comment: Make sure you are using ADAL.NET v2 (not v3.) Let me know if that does not solve your issue.

Comment: Ok. I will download the v2 dll. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Nicknow:

I tried the v2 dll and now the authContextToken works.But I get an error saying:
"The request body must contain the following parameter: Client_secret or client_assertion".
Any idea why this comes up?

Comment: @uba2012 - What was the solution to your **Client_secret or client_assertion** issue? It might be helpful to someone who lands on this question in the future.